# Listing Polls and choices on same page

Tags: views, polls

I have couple of polls, I want all of them on one page.
Like this:

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to do this . create a view of poll and show display as content (full content) not field and you're done

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i need one submit button  to submit all polls.

Comment: i will tell you , let me search :)

Comment: I used "webforms" as an alternate . I don't think it's possible with default "Drupal polls or advanced polls" .

Comment: Yes , you're right

Comment: @brainHax try to use Pollfield (https://drupal.org/project/pollfield) , it gives you a field and you'll have unlimeited poll